# Embed UITableView in Scrollview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I know Apple don't recommend to Embed `UITableView` in `UIScrollview`.

So this is what I am trying to do:
I have a registration form with fields embedded in `UIScrollview`,
for some fields I create a drop menu by presenting `UITableView`, the problem is when the `UITableView` appears with my object the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` not responding.

If there is another way it I will happy to hear, if not how can I fix it in the Current situation , thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to add your drop menu(UITableView) on self.view or on the Window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't add the table as a subview of the scroll view, add it as a subview of the superview of the scroll view (and, consider adding it into a container view which detects touches outside the table to dismiss it from the screen without any selection being made).

If your 'root' view for the controller is the scroll view, change your view hierarchy to use a plain view as the root and have the scroll view as a subview of that.

You may also want to use `bringSubviewToFront:` to ensure that the presentation is correct.